# Laravel 9 "Auth guard [api] is not defined." Errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I had errors postman. I write api on laravel 9 framework and I request on postman to laravel api Request Login successfull. Api return token to me but I reach my user detail on postman show this error to me

```
   "message": "Auth guard [api] is not defined.",
   "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
   "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager.php",
   "line": 84,
   "trace": [
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager.php",
           "line": 68,
           "function": "resolve",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php",
           "line": 63,
           "function": "guard",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php",
           "line": 42,
           "function": "authenticate",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 103,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
           "line": 723,
           "function": "then",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
           "line": 698,
           "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
           "line": 662,
           "function": "runRoute",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
           "line": 651,
           "function": "dispatchToRoute",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "dispatch",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 128,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\DisableBrowserCache.php",
           "line": 19,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Livewire\\DisableBrowserCache",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
           "line": 21,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
           "line": 31,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
           "line": 21,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php",
           "line": 40,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
           "line": 27,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
           "line": 86,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
           "line": 52,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies.php",
           "line": 39,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 167,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
           "line": 103,
           "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
           "line": 142,
           "function": "then",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
           "line": 111,
           "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\public\\index.php",
           "line": 52,
           "function": "handle",
           "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
           "type": "->"
       },
       {
           "file": "C:\\Users\\Berat\\Desktop\\quiz\\quiz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\resources\\server.php",
           "line": 16,
           "function": "require_once"
       }
   ]
}
```

how do solve this problem ? I watched one video and I did not solve this problem. I tested my project don't have a problem

Comment: Have you added Bearer token in your headers inside your postman request?

Comment: Share your route code or where ever this is throwing from

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't added driver of api guards in config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
   'api' => [
      'driver' => 'passport',
      'provider' => 'users',
   ],
]
```

For more details, please see laravel passport installation link
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#installation

Thanks